# Is it possible to disable widget without widget.xml changes?

Tags: widgets, widget

I have extension with widget.xml file where there are 5 defined widgets. 1 of the widgets is available only to premium customers. I don't want this widget to show up inside `Widget type` selection in CMS->Pages when you click insert new widget icon.

Is there any way to programmatically remove widget without removing it from widget.xml?

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way I've found was to just hide the select options via CSS:

```
#select_widget_type option[value="sales/widget_guest_form"] {
    display: none;
}
```